# Got problem with array and 'inhomogeneous shape'

Tags: python, numpy

My code considers a three-dimensional graph, however, I needed to add "s1" dependent on "t", that is, so that it is substituted depending on the time of the other. If you look without s1, then the code runs good.
When add "s1" got error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (6,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I tried different solutions, use arrays, lists, overwrite, check the contents - but there is no imaginary part in these arrays.
I found in some topics that rolling back the numpy version helps, but I get an error when rolling back, only the latest version is installed. Maybe there are other ways to fix the problem?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

b = 0.5182
c = 0.22439
d = 1.465
a1 = 30
a2 = 30
eps = 0.1
s = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100000)
n = s[1]
s1 = []
for i in range(1000):
    s1.append(s[i])
as1 = np.asarray (s1)
def f(x):
    if x<=-1.2:
        f = 0.528
    if -1.2<x<1.2:
        f = x*(1-x*x)
    else:
        f = -0.528
    return f
def dH_dt(H, t=0,*s1):
        return np.array([(H[1]+s1),
                     -H[0]-b*H[1]+H[2],
                     c*(a1*f(H[0])-H[2])-d*H[1],

                     (H[4]+eps*(H[0]+H[5]))+s1,
                     -H[3]-b*H[4]+H[5],
                     c*(a2*f(H[3])-H[5])-d*H[4]])

                        
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
H0 = [0.05, 0.07, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09]
H, infodict = integrate.odeint(dH_dt, H0, t, args=(s1,), full_output=True)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(H[:,0], H[:,1], H[:,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: show the actual error message.  You/we need to determine exactly where it's happening, and why, before randomly trying fixes,

Comment: `inhomogeneous` has nothing to do with `imaginary`.

Comment: @hpaulj i will add screen with actual error

Comment: This kind of `valueerror` is the recent version's way of saying you are trying to make a 'ragged' array.

Answer (score 1):

In your `dH_dt` function, `H` is a numpy array. In the first element of your return, you have `H[1]`, which is of type `np.float64` and `s1`, which is a `tuple` containing a `list`. When you do `H[1] + s1`, numpy will convert `s1` into a numpy array and add the value of `H[1]` to every element, giving you a numpy array result. You're creating a return value where some of the elements are being converted to numpy arrays while others (i.e. the terms without `s1`) are just `np.float64`. This is creating a ragged array, which the integrator doesn't know how to handle.

At the moment, I cannot suggest any changes because I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: i wanted to make it so that with each calculation, the i value of S was added to H[1], that is, it was H[1] + s[i]. 
But now it seems to me that the only way out of this situation is a loop instead of a function

Comment: @HUR1EY I still do not understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, if you want different a calculation for each element of `s` you have do that yourself.  `odeint` does not have that kind of iteration/vectorization mechanism.  When in doubt reread the docs.  You can't fudge the input/output requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If I change your function to be more diagnostic:

```
def dH_dt(H, t=0,*s1):
    ...:         alist = [(H[1]+s1),
    ...:                      -H[0]-b*H[1]+H[2],
    ...:                      c*(a1*f(H[0])-H[2])-d*H[1],
    ...: 
    ...:                      (H[4]+eps*(H[0]+H[5]))+s1,
    ...:                      -H[3]-b*H[4]+H[5],
    ...:                      c*(a2*f(H[3])-H[5])-d*H[4]]
    ...:         print([i.shape for i in alist])
    ...:         arr = np.array(alist)
    ...:         return arr
```

The run shows that it's trying to make an array from a mix of shapes - scalars and (1,1000)

```
H, infodict = integrate.odeint(dH_dt, H0, t, args=(s1,), full_output=True)
[(1, 1000), (), (), (1, 1000), (), ()]
```

error is in the line:

```
arr = np.array(alist)
```

Even if I set `s1` to be a scalar, float, I get the error with list shapes of

```
[(1,), (), (), (1,), (), ()]
```

I have to change the `dH+dt` signature to `def dH_dt(H, t, s1):` to get it to run for a scalar `s1`.

This function has to return an array the same shape as `H0`, (6,)

```
`dy/dt = func(y, t, ...)`
```

It uses `lsoda from the FORTRAN library odepack`.  `lsoda` is compiled, and can't not do 'broadcasting' or 'iteration' as you might expect from pure python/numpy code.  It doesn't have the usual `numpy` flexibility with dimensions.

In short, you can't do multiple `odeint` runs with one call to that function.